# NSMutableArray replacing object insted of adding

Tags: ios, object, nsmutablearray

I'm using a NSMutableArray to store an object called poligonon. This object has a NSMutableArray as property to store coordinates X.
But when I add the second object, the first object on the array transform itself. All objects on the array must be differents, but they are equal the last object in the array.

Exemple:

`coordArrayX` is a property (NSMutableArray)

`-saveDataIntoArray`

```
{
poligonon.coorArrayX = coordArrayX;
arrayPoligonon addObject: poligonon;
}
```

The first time that the user clicks to save, the first coordinate is 74.
Now, he creates a new poligonon that has coordinate 45, and add to the array.

When the user checks, the first poligonon has coordinate = 45.

How to solve?

Comment: Are you re-using the same object (poligonon)?  You almost have to be.  Try: `[arrayPoligonon addObject:[poligonon copy]];`.

Comment: yes. I used the same object to store in the first array and that worked. Now it always return the last object array. I also tried to init a new object and add this one, releasing later

Answer (score 0):

Each and every time you are adding the same `poligonon` to the array and overwriting the value of `coorArrayX`.

Instead of,

```
{
  poligonon.coorArrayX = coordArrayX;
  arrayPoligonon addObject: poligonon;
}
```

Try this,

```
{
  poligonon = [[Poligonon alloc] init];
  poligonon.coorArrayX = coordArrayX;
  [arrayPoligonon addObject:poligonon];
}
```

Comment: Do not work. But this poligonon has a property float called area. This variable is working fine, they aren't equal.

Comment: @FelipeBoszczowski, What is the issue now after this change? and what is coorArrayX? float? area will work fine since that is not a pointer. The others are pointers and that is why you need to allocate a new memory for that.